# Is it possible to link the 'view-source:' of an external page?

Tags: html, view-source

I tried using `<a href="view-source:google.com">External Source</a>` but that just returns a broken link.

Comment: I believe that this will be browser specific. Is there a particular browser that you are targeting?

Comment: Nope, just wondering if there was a standard for it. I just came across this tutorial which leads me to believe that it isn't possible without a hack http://css-tricks.com/make-a-view-source-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema/protocol `http:` is missing:

```
<a href="view-source:http:google.com">External Source</a>`
```

Test with the scURIple (scriple):

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html><a href="view-source:http:google.com">External Source</a></html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755819/view-source-in-href-shows-error-in-console

Answer (score 3):

If you're just going to need the HTML source of a webpage, and not anything else, and you're willing to use a server-side language, there is the option of using `curl`, `file_get_contents`, or [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get the HTML of a website, and then display that on your own page between `<code></code>` or `<pre></pre>` tags. This would look something like this in PHP

```
include("simplehtmldom.php");
$html=file_get_html($url);
echo "<pre>$html</pre>;
```

Obviously this should be formatted or prettyprinted. Take a look at [Google Code prettifier](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to do this. If you want to get the source of *your own page*, you could use Javascript, and do this:

```
var html=document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

I'm not sure how that would work for fetching external pages, but you could try an `iframe` for that, like this

```
document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Comment: I haven't used PHP lately, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like that would include the unescaped content directly into your output. Including source from an external site without escaping it is a serious security risk.

Comment: @NickUrban I don't think so, especially if you're simply getting the html with `file_get_html`

Comment: If you are injecting unescaped code, it could easily include <script> tags. As soon as you inject a script tag from an untrusted source, all bets are off. They can send your users to a phishing site, harvest information from the current page, etc. Since the HTML is being injected by your own server-side script, they can even read cookies from your domain and steal browser sessions, etc. In other words, unless you are sure that the HTML is being sanitized properly, it is very dangerous.

Comment: @NickUrban good points, I'd forgotten about that. probably, you just want to replace all special chars like <>&"' with their entity numbers

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to outputting everything in a `<pre>` block, consider returning a different content type.  In your response headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Then, you can simply return the HTML content and it will be displayed as plain-text in the browser.

Comment: this is... from PHP? Thanks.

Comment: @DanRosenstark No, it's just an HTTP response header.  You can send it with whatever you're running server-side.